# LINQ error with ToList

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
(from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
    join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"]
    join n in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation") on r["opportunityid"] equals ((EntityReference)n["objectid"]).Id into opp
    from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty().ToList()
    where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
```

with the `ToList()` I get this error:

> The method 'GroupJoin' cannot follow the method 'Join' or is not
>   supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call
>   the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported
>   methods.

If I take the ToList off I get the same error. Is there away to fix this or am I doing it totally wrong?

Thanks!

**Side Note:** I'm using the DefaultIfEmpty because I need it to still pull down records even if the record its joined to is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your grouping, so this should work:

```
(from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
    join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"]
    join n in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("annotation") on r["opportunityid"] equals ((EntityReference)n["objectid"]).Id
    where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
```

Change

```
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
```

to

```
join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact").DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks, That works for the most part. No errors, but I had the DefaultIfEmpty because some records in contacts have null records and I want to still pull them done if the record its joined to has a null. This possible with this query?